# Falcon 7B LLM Evaluation using TruLens

Tags: python, model-evaluations, llm

The problem I am facing is after defining the prompt template, creating a chain using Langchain, defining the huggingface evaluation module from trulens_eval to check the toxicity of the response and then when finally passing the prompt through truchain, the response that I am getting is incomplete response like truncated response.

```
import os
os.environ["HUGGINGFACE_API_KEY"]='<YOUR_OWN_API_KEY>'
os.environ["HUGGINGFACEHUB_API_TOKEN"]='<YOUR_OWN_API_KEY>'
from langchain import PromptTemplate
from langchain.chains import  LLMChain
from langchain.prompts.chat import (ChatPromptTemplate,HumanMessagePromptTemplate)
from langchain import HuggingFaceHub
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from trulens_eval import TruChain

full_prompt = HumanMessagePromptTemplate(
    prompt=PromptTemplate(
        template="Please provide detailed helpful response with relevant background information for the following: {prompt}. Provide a complete paragraph of the response",
            input_variables=["prompt"],
        )
    )
chat_prompt_template = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages([full_prompt])
model = HuggingFaceHub(repo_id='tiiuae/falcon-7b-instruct', model_kwargs={"temperature":0.5})
chain = LLMChain(llm=model, prompt=chat_prompt_template)

from trulens_eval import Feedback, Huggingface, Query
hugs=Huggingface()
f_toxicity=Feedback(hugs.not_toxic).on(text=Query.RecordOutput)

truchain=TruChain(chain,app_id="testapp_validation",feedbacks=[f_toxicity])
llm_response3=truchain("What is Machine Learning and Artificial Intelligence")
display(llm_response3)
```

In this code above, before starting the code I have defined by API keys.

Comment: Even if I use flan t5 model then also the responses are incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

You most probably need to play with the number of tokens your pipeline generates. I think the logical way to put these would be extending the line with `model = HuggingFaceHub(repo_id='tiiuae/falcon-7b-instruct', model_kwargs={"temperature":0.5})` in a following way:

```py
model = HuggingFaceHub(repo_id='tiiuae/falcon-7b-instruct', model_kwargs={"temperature":0.5, max_new_tokens=512})
```

But be aware that the generation might continue beyond the specified number and you need to implement some heuristics on top. The falcon I worked with doesn't stop generation itself quite often.